# Bootstrap Collapse:How to deactivate other buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need help in using Bootstrap collapse.
I created 3 buttons which are collapsing. The thing, that in my case it is only logical if only one button is collapsed.
So I want to deactivate other buttons when I'm clicking on a button.
Is there maybe any method to do this?

Thank you very much.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseexample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseexample1">some example text</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseexample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseexample2">some text</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="collapseexample1">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                random text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="collapseexample2">
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4>
                random text again
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simplified example of my code.

Comment: Share some code or error you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting any errors.But if I'm activatíng two or more buttons, the texts or whatever are not getting their right positions as I am using responsive columns.

Comment: I am going to share code in few seconds.

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use

Comment: I am using version 4.0.

Comment: I think there's an extra `div` tag, check indentation

Comment: Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a jquery function for it. Get your button elements and toggle their disabled state when one of them is clicked. You should even find quite a lot of ready to go solutions for it if you search "bootstrap collapse expand one at the time"

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. I guess it is the right way. I thought maybe there are other ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I'm going to use acordions.
First, I didn't like them, but they are looking a way better on small devices.